# Grails 3.3.8 does not reload the changes made to the project

Tags: grails

I have a project with grails 3.3.8, the problem is that once I edit a controller or a gsp file, the changes are not reflected in the web browser even though the following message appears when it detects a change:

```
Controller.groovy change, compiling...
```

I have tried to start the app in the following way:

```
grails -reloading run-app.
```

And also with:

```
// File: build.gradle
import grails.util.Environment
...
bootRun {

    final Boolean reloadEnabled =
            Boolean.valueOf(
                    System.properties[Environment.RELOAD_ENABLED])

    if (reloadEnabled) {
        systemProperty Environment.RELOAD_ENABLED, reloadEnabled
    }

}
...
```

> `grails -Dgrails.env=custom -Dgrails.reload.enabled=true run-app`

Comment: I cannot recreate that.  Reloading appears to work as expected for me.

Comment: Do you have JDK 1.7?

Comment: "Do you have JDK 1.7?" - Yes, I have JDK 1.7.

Answer (score 2):

According to this link https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207602705-Grails-3-not-automatically-hot-swapping-changed-code-after-upgrading-to-2016-1-3 it appears that hot reloading of classes only suns to happen in grails 3.3.x when the environment is set to development. 
I've not been able to confirm that for myself however. I notice you are providing "custom" as your environment. Maybe try changing it to the development environment and see if that helps.

Also just want to confirm that your not just seeing behaviour listed in [Grails auto recompile never completes (Grails 3.3.6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52502136/grails-auto-recompile-never-completes-grails-3-3-6#comment91957403_52502136)